# Deserialization Exception in Plugin when using Early Bound Entities

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I wrote several plugin for previous CRM versions, most of them using Early Bound entities.

Right now I am writing a plugin for version 2015 with just one custom entity; the plugin contains the generated entity definition (early-bound entity class).

As soon as I attempt to retrieve an entity using the Organization Service in the Plugin Pipeline I get the following exception:

```
Element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts:Entity' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts:new_TestEntity'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name 'new_TestEntity' and namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts'.
```

Plugin has a ProxyTypesAssembly attribute.

I am attempting to intercept the RetrieveMultiple and Retrieve messages. It's all working. It faults as soon as I attempt to execute a Retrieve within the plugin execution context (using the pipeline's org service).

Comment: Is the code in multiple libraries and - if yes - do you use ILMerge? Can you share the stack trace? Your problem sounds familiar; trying to remember when I had this issue and how I solved it...

Comment: I am not using ILMerge. I only exported those classes I needed from crmsvcutil and included them into the plugin source.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have changed your entity model without regenerating the early bound classes. Try regenerating your early bound entities.

Looks like the same issue as described in [CRM 2015 SDK : The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32179887/crm-2015-sdk-the-deserializer-has-no-knowledge-of-any-type-that-maps-to-this-n/32189274#32189274)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The other question is not about a plugin. I have no issues using early bound entities from standalone applications.

Comment: Are the standalone applications using the same version of early bound classes? If its the issue I think it is the hosting of the code isn't important, it all about the early bound classes not matching what is in CRM.